# find() inside reduce() method returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects; districts and userCounts. I am trying to reduce districts and find userCounts inside reduce

```
const result = districts.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const findUser = userCounts.find(({ _id }) => _id === curr._id)
        console.log(findUser)
    })
```

all findUser is returning `undefined`

districts:

```
[
        {
            _id: '5efc41d74664920022b6c016',
            name: 'name1'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc41a44664920022b6c015',
            name: 'name2'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b',
            name: 'name3'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc41794664920022b6c014',
            name: 'name 4'
        }
    ]
```

userCounts:

```
    [
        { _id: '5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b', totalCount: 3 },
        { _id: '5efc41794664920022b6c014', totalCount: 1 }
    ]
```

Comment: give full sample code which can help.

Comment: yes because you does not return anything in your reduce

Comment: its returning undefined in console.log. return is not necessary for it

Comment: With the example values you've provided it's working fine on my end in Chrome. Perhaps the issue is in the JS interpreter you are using? Are you running in browser or in node? What version?

Comment: Its also working fine on playcode.io that I had tried. but not on my pc. https://playcode.io/662873/. My machine is running in node 12.13.1

Comment: Please read the documentation for `reduce`. This is not how it is used. You are not returning the accumulator inside `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

well `.filter()` with `.every()` is better use case here

```js
let districts = [
  {
    _id: "5efc41d74664920022b6c016",
    name: "name1",
  },
  {
    _id: "5efc41a44664920022b6c015",
    name: "name2",
  },
  {
    _id: "5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b",
    name: "name3",
  },
  {
    _id: "5efc41794664920022b6c014",
    name: "name 4",
  },
];

let userCounts = [
  { _id: "5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b", totalCount: 3 },
  { _id: "5efc41794664920022b6c014", totalCount: 1 },
];

const result = districts.filter((dist) => {
  return userCounts.some(({ _id }) => _id === dist._id);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I also wanted to modify the districts array after find() like districts = [{_id: '',  name : 'name1', user: 3}]  so I used reduce method

Answer (score 0):

```js
const districs=[
        {
            _id: '5efc41d74664920022b6c016',
            name: 'name1'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc41a44664920022b6c015',
            name: 'name2'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b',
            name: 'name3'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc41794664920022b6c014',
            name: 'name 4'
        }
    ]
    
    const userCounts= [
        { _id: '5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b', totalCount: 3 },
        { _id: '5efc41794664920022b6c014', totalCount: 1 }
    ]
    
    let filtered=userCounts.map(item=>{
    return districs.find(elemnt=>elemnt._id===item._id)
    })
    console.log(filtered)
```

here you go, you can modify it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to use `reduce` and modify your array:

```
 const result = districts.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            const findUser = userCounts.filter(({ _id }) => _id === curr._id)
            return [...acc, {...curr , user:findUser.length > 0 ? findUser[0].totalCount :0 }]
    },[])
```

```js
const districts = [
        {
            _id: '5efc41d74664920022b6c016',
            name: 'name1'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc41a44664920022b6c015',
            name: 'name2'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b',
            name: 'name3'
        },
        {
            _id: '5efc41794664920022b6c014',
            name: 'name 4'
        }
    ]

const userCounts =   [
        { _id: '5efc2d84caa7964dcd843a7b', totalCount: 3 },
        { _id: '5efc41794664920022b6c014', totalCount: 1 }
    ]

const result = districts.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const findUser = userCounts.filter(({ _id }) => _id === curr._id)
        return [...acc, {...curr , user:findUser.length > 0 ? findUser[0].totalCount :0 }]
},[])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is what I exactly tried but its returning an array of obj like this: {
[0]       '$__': [InternalCache],
[0]       isNew: false,
[0]       errors: undefined,
[0]       '$locals': {},
[0]       '$op': null,
[0]       _doc: [Object],
[0]       '$init': true,
[0]       user: 0
[0]     }

Comment: May be there is something wrong in your code, you can check my code is working fine